# Swift UIView: make a path always be at the end of person's finger?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cashapelayer

OK, I am new to UIBezierPaths but I need to have a path whose endpoint updates according to where the user's finger is. It should change in `touchesMoved`

So far I have:

```
func customInit() {
    print("init scene")
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300))

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}

override public func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    var touch : UITouch! =  touches.first! as UITouch
    var location = touch.location(in: self)

    path.move(to: location)
}
```

I thought this would update the path endpoint but nothing happens beyond drawing the original line. I would like to not use SKScene for this, but don't know what is going wrong.

How can I make a line always have a point at the point of user's tap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close! You're missing just a few things.

When `touchesMoved` is called, you need to update the path and re-assign it to the `CAShapeLayer` so that it can be re-drawn. Right now you are just making a modification to the path object, but not re-drawing it.

**Final Code**

```
class DrawingView: UIView {

    let startingPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        customInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        customInit()
    }

    func customInit() {

        backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        path.move(to: startingPoint)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))

        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

        let touch =  touches.first as! UITouch
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        path.removeAllPoints()
        path.move(to: startingPoint)
        path.addLine(to: location)

        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

    }

}
```

**Final Result**

[image: gif of the line endpoint moving on touch]

(tested in an Xcode 8.3.2 playground)

---

**Update:**

To make the line disappear when the touch is released, use `touchesEnded`. Inside this method, simply remove the points on the path and reassign it to the shapeLayer so the view is updated.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    path.removeAllPoints()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great explanation

Comment: I have a question - how would I make it snap back to being nothing (start and end are same points) when I release my finger?